# Resolve singleton in Bind<T>().ToMethod

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, ninject

What is Ninject 3 equivalent of this code:

```
Bind<ISession>().ToMethod(ctx => ctx.Kernel.Get<INHibernateSessionFactoryBuilder>()
            .GetSessionFactory()
            .OpenSession())
            .Using<OnePerRequestBehavior>();
```

I know that I can use `InRequestScope` instead of `Using<OnePerRequestBehavior>` but how to replace `ctx.Kernel.Get<INHibernateSessionFactoryBuilder>`? (`INHibernateSessionFactoryBuilder` is a singleton)

Comment: Why do you want to replace the call to `ctx.Kernel.Get<INHibernateSessionFactoryBuilder>`?

Comment: Because ctx.Kernel doesn't contain Get method...

Comment: It does, you just need to add `using Ninject;` as it's an extension method.

Comment: Yup I only had `using Ninject.Modules`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, just to clarify - since this is in a Module, you can still access `ctx.Kernel.Get<T>` but you need to add a `using Ninject;` to the module too as `Kernel.Get<T>` is exposed as an extension method.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so here is the final code that works for me:

```
using Infrastructure.Data;
using NHibernate;
using Ninject;
using Ninject.Modules;
using Ninject.Web.Common;

namespace Infrastructure.DependencyResolution
{
    public class SessionModule : NinjectModule
    {
        public override void Load()
        {
            Bind<INHibernateSessionFactoryBuilder>().To<NHibernateSessionFactoryBuilder>().InSingletonScope();

            Bind<ISession>().ToMethod(ctx => ctx.Kernel.Get<INHibernateSessionFactoryBuilder>()
                .GetSessionFactory()
                .OpenSession())
                .InRequestScope();      
        }
    }
}
```

With this module loaded with Ninject bootstrapper I can use repositories with NHibernate session without the need for NH reference in Web project...